# Users $Skip and $Count

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

The Microsoft Graph api does not support $skip and $count for when making calls to the users collection.

While I understand that skipToken allows you some pagination abilities, it limits limits the pagination capabilities for the users page in my application.

The AD tenant in using has over 6000 users and it takes to long to download them all.

I’m about to cache them on the server and check for updates periodically, but I wanted to check to make sure that I am not missing something.

Is there a way to use the $count and $skip or an equivalent that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2):

> The Microsoft Graph Api does not support $skip and $count for when
>   making calls to the users collection.

that's correct, here is a excerpt from [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters):

> `$count` is not supported for collections of resources that derive
>   from directoryObject like collections of users or groups.

And same goes to [`$skip` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#skip-parameter), it is not supported for [List users endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

For [paging scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) [`$skipToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#skiptoken-parameter) parameter needs to be utilized instead along with `$top` parameter.

**Example**

Assuming page size is `100` items, the following query retrieves users for the first page:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=100
```

If the result contains more than 100 users, Microsoft Graph will return an `@odata:nextLink` property. Next page results are retrieved by sending the url value of the `@odata:nextLink` property:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=100&$skiptoken={skipToken}
```

Comment: Yes, but this requires me to store the token for navigation per session (or in the users browser), and does not indicate how many total results a search on users returns